# How to Add minOccurs in Attributes in XML Schemas?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, dtd

I can't declare a XML attribute with minOccurs

This is for Oxygen XML Editor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="Albums">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="artist">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:attribute name="personorgroup" type="xsd:string" use="required">
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="groupmembernames" type="xsd:string" minOccur="0">
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

Well formed document for schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a `minOccurs` attribute within an `attribute` definition because an `attribute` can only occur once in an XML `element`. You can specify the `use`, as you have in your other `attribute`, which allows it to be `prohibited` (occurs=0), `optional` (occurs=0-1) or `required` (occurs=1) but the concept of `minOccurs` is meaningless.

From the specification

> Well-formedness constraint: Unique Att Spec
>
> An attribute name MUST NOT appear more than once in the same start-tag
>   or empty-element tag.

And a link to the specification

[Well-formedness constraint: Unique Att Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#uniqattspec)

Comment: Can I do maxOccurs?

Comment: No, for the same reason. The `use` attribute is your only way of restricting it.

Comment: Can I ask why you downvoted my post? I'm simply a beginner seeking advice what have I done wrong?

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with this project due Friday for me and whenever I post here people downvote me immediately or put me down for not knowing. I want to know so I can learn!

Comment: Fine by me. If you're happy with my answer you could mark it as the answer. :-)

Comment: Is it the green check I clicked that

Comment: That's the one. Good luck!

Comment: This might be a bit weird but I really am struggling on this and need guidance. I'm going to bed soon but would u be ok with sharing contact information and helping me out on the project? I would be happy to pay u!

Comment: Sorry, far too busy but I'll happily answer questions if I see them.

Comment: @VinnieRoy Ignore downvotes unless they come with an explanation. There's no way of finding out what the downvoter intended to convey, therefore no point fretting about it. I've seen downvotes which I'm sure arose just because the person isn't a fan of the technology you happen to be using. Conversely, I'm pretty sure I've had downvotes because my question is considered critical of a technology (or viewpoint) that someone considers beyond criticism...